# can't print linear regression in WEKA

Tags: regression, linear-regression, weka

I have dataset consist of 22 attributes and 500 rows. All are numeric values. When I apply linear regression on it, the following message is appear:
can't print linear regression 
as show in picture (attached).
when I apply the same step on the part of my dataset (not all 22 attributes and 500 rows) or on another dataset, every thing is ok.
What is the problem? 
any expert can help me please!

[image: the output]

Answer (score 0):

Get the source code of Weka.

Remove the *stupid* catch-all exception handling (antipattern!) or at least make sure to actually print the root cause of the error.

```
try {
... Somewhere here there must be an error ...
} catch (Exception e) {
  return "Can't print Linear Regression!";
}
```

Then debug why this error occurs.

As the Weka code of linear regression *swallowed* the actual error, we can't help you until you work with the Weka source to debug this yourself.